# TypeScript Generic Collection: List

Tags: list, typescript, collections

I am trying to learn TypeScript, and need some advice on implementing generic collection types. I put the dictionary and HashSet in another question, here I'd like any advice on my list type.

Especially the ForEach-Operation looks a bit strange. I think I found it in another question here, and "improved" by returning true or false to give feedback if the iteration was stopped early or completed.

```
import { IForEachFunction } from "./IForEachFunction"

export class List<T> {
    private _items: Array<T>;

    public constructor() {
        this._items = [];
    }

    public get Count(): number {
        return this._items.length;
    }

    public Item(index: number): T {
        return this._items[index];
    }

    public Add(value: T): void {
        this._items.push(value);
    }

    public RemoveAt(index: number): void {
        this._items.splice(index, 1);
    }

    public Remove(value: T): void {
        let index = this._items.indexOf(value);
        this.RemoveAt(index);
    }

    public ForEach(callback: IForEachFunction<T>): boolean {
        for (const element of this._items) {
            if (callback(element) === false) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

The ForEach-Iteration relies on an interface from another file:

```
export interface IForEachFunction<T> {
    (callback: T): boolean | void;
}
```

You would use my list and the ForEach-Method like this:

```
let myList: List<a_type> = new List<a_type>();
let completed: boolean = myList.ForEach(xyz => {
    // do something with xyz
    return false; // aborts the iteration
    return true; // continues with the next element
});
if (completed) // we can see what happened "during" the iteration
```

I think this is not bad, but I'd appreciate any input. I am not sure if I use the === correctly.
Another question which I really like to know: How could I define a function with the interface IForEachFunction? I do not really "re-use" that interface visibly, I always declare an anonymous method as shown above. If I wanted to call a method having the interface definition, is that possible?

Thanks!
Ralf

Comment: FWIW, [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) does the same thing your `ForEach` method does. I would stick to a plain array instead of writing a wrapper.

Comment: This question seems a bit too broad, since I can't figure out how to give a self-contained answer that doesn't tackle all different things:  Your ForEach function looks fine.  Your use of `===` is fine.  You can define a function with an interface definition like so: `var forEachFunc: IForEachFunction<string> = function(s) { return !!s; }`.  Methods and properties conventially start with lowercase letters.  I assume you are implementing the `List` class for your own enrichment and not for use in "the real world", since as others have said, you'd be better off using a js array in most cases.

Answer (score -1):

One problem I see is that you have an interface instance:

```
callback: IForEachFunction<T>
```

This contains a method called

```
callback()
```

But you only call callback once. You would have call callback() method inside your interface:

```
callback.callback()
```

Also your code looks like it is inspired by C# or Java. In TypeScript you would often just use an array. This simplifies certain code constructs.

Comment: No, `IForEachFunction<T>` does not contain a method named `callback`.  It is a callable function-like interface with a *parameter* named `callback`.  Look carefully at the parenthesis placement.

Comment: his confusion goes to show that @Ralf's declaration is more confusing than it need be: the `callback` parameter is *not* a callback; it's just a value of type `T`; and a callable interface with no other properties is essentially just a function type.  I'd suggest something like `export type IForEachFunction<T> = (t: T) => boolean | void;` instead, which acts more or less the same and is more clear.